# libGDX iOS module, how to redirect to the AppStore for rating and review?

Tags: ios, libgdx

I made a game in libGDX. It's only for Android, but I'm porting it to iOS (MobiDevelop's RoboVM fork) now. In the game there is a button which brings user to Google Play Store to make a review. Java code in the android module which is responsible for redirection is simple like this:

```
activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + PACKAGE_NAME)));
```

But I'm unable to find how to do it for iOS in module ios. I just want to show / redirect to the Apple App Store site/page with my game after button click. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an abstraction in libgdx to open an URL in generic way :

On iOS Store,

1. For publisher/moreGames you need **Apple Developer Account Link**

   ```
   Gdx.net.openURI("Apple Developer Account Link");
   ```
2. For rating, You've app-ID of all you app, through which you can go to single app.

   ```
   Gdx.net.openURI("Your App url available on AppStore");
   ```

Even you can use flag,  `if(Gdx.app.getType() == Application.ApplicationType.iOS)` for platform specific redirection.

Check [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320805/apple-developer-account-link/320811#320811) thread for more information about how you can get Apple Developer Account Link.